# Error in knitting RMarkdown: x and y must have the same value for correlation analysis

Tags: r

I was doing correlation analysis with the housing data. After dividing the data into test and train samples, I had the following data for correlation:

```
cor.test(test_sample$SalePrice,test_sample$OverallQual,method = "pearson",data=test_sample)
```

When I run the code in Rmarkdown, the result is perfectly produced. However, when I try knitting the work into word document, I get the following error:

```
label: unnamed-chunk-15
Quitting from lines 185-186 (EDA-and-Visualization-Final-Project.Rmd) 
Error in cor.test.default(test_sample$SalePrice, test_sample$OverallQual,  : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> cor.test -> cor.test.default

Execution halted
```

When I checked the length of `test_sample$SalePrice` and `test_sample$OverallQual` (i.e. `x` and `y`, I found out that they are both 1459.

What could be the problem, and how can I solve it?

```
Here is the sample data
 SalePrice LotArea OverallQuality OverallCondition MasVnrArea TotalBsmtSF
1     208500    8450              7                5        196         856
2     181500    9600              6                8          0        1262
3     223500   11250              7                5        162         920
4     140000    9550              7                5          0         756
5     143000   14115              5                5          0         796
6     307000   10084              8                5        186        1686
7     200000   10382              7                6        240        1107
8     129900    6120              7                5          0         952
9     118000    7420              5                6          0         991
10    129500   11200              5                5          0        1040
   YrSold GarageArea X1stFlrSF X2ndFlrSF
1    2008        548       856       854
2    2007        460      1262         0
3    2008        608       920       866
4    2006        642       961       756
5    2009        480       796       566
6    2007        636      1694         0
7    2009        484      1107       983
8    2008        468      1022       752
9    2008        205      1077         0
10   2008        384      1040         0
```

Comment: Please make the problem reproducible with some data.

Comment: Hi, thanks. how can I do that?

Comment: Provide (toy) data in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, kindly check the edited question. I have included the first 10 observations of the data. It is the housing data obtained from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

Comment: Note the difference between your data: `OverallQuality` and code: `OverallQual`. Is there something else in your workspace?

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. I am grateful. I had two datasets. I have corrected the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is not completely reproducible, but there are several issues: inconsistency of names between data and code and incorrect formula syntax. Here an example that should work, with two different forms to call `cor.test`:

````
---
title: "Markdown example"
output: html_document
---


```{r}
test_sample <- structure(list(
  SalePrice = c(208500, 181500, 223500, 140000,
                143000, 307000, 200000, 129900, 118000, 129500),
  LotArea = c(8450, 9600, 11250, 9550, 14115, 10084, 10382, 6120, 7420, 11200),
  OverallQuality = c(7, 6, 7, 7, 5, 8, 7, 7, 5, 5),
  OverallCondition = c(5, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5),
  MasVnrArea = c(196, 0, 162, 0, 0, 186, 240, 0, 0, 0),
  TotalBsmtSF = c(856, 1262, 920, 756, 796, 1686,
                  1107, 952, 991, 1040),
  YrSold = c(2008, 2007, 2008, 2006, 2009, 2007, 2009, 2008, 2008, 2008),
  GarageArea = c(548, 460, 608, 642, 480, 636, 484, 468, 205, 384),
  X1stFlrSF = c(856,1262, 920, 961, 796, 1694, 1107, 1022, 1077, 1040),
  X2ndFlrSF = c(854, 0, 866, 756, 566, 0, 983, 752, 0, 0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L)
)
```

```{r}
cor.test(test_sample$SalePrice, test_sample$OverallQuality, method = "pearson")
```


```{r}
cor.test(~ SalePrice + OverallQuality, data = test_sample)
```
````

A few notes:

- If you use the dollar syntax, the data argument should be be omitted
- the formula syntax is different from what one would expect when comparing it with a linear model, because correlation does not distinguish between an independent and a dependent variable. Examples can be fond in the `cor.test`help page.
- `method = "pearson"` is the default anyway, so it can be omitted. One can also keep it in for better readability.
- Please note also how to provide a reproducible example in a way to make it more user-friendly for people who want to help. The structure can be created with `dput(test_sample)`

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually discovered that inconsistency in naming was one of the major issues. I am grateful.